# SSL Certificate in ISA Server 2004

Tags: exchange-2003, ssl-certificate, outlook-web-app, isa-server

I have a ssl certificate for Exchange which has been installed on IIS for OWA but in order for this certificate to be presented to the user when they login, i.e. visit OWA, it has to be installed also on the ISA server.  This is where I have become stuck.  I have installed the certificate in the Personal section, but when I go to point the web listener to the ssl certificate it is never in the list.

So, my question is, am I putting the certificate in the right place on the server?  If so, where should it go?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the certificates snap-in to MMC, you must choose to view certificates for the computer account, then add the certificate to the Personal section.

The certificate must also have the private key included with it.

You don't normally need to restart ISA services for the certificate to show up in the web listener configuration window, but on one occasion it didn't show until after a reboot for me.

On one occasion (where I was restoring a certificate from a backup) the certificate wasn't showing that the private key was included (when it was), and I had to (I think) repair the certificate using certutil on the ISA server.

Comment: Thank you, I thought as I had the certificate, I could just install that. but you have to export it from IIS first  See http://www.isaserver.org/articles/exportsslcert.html for more info